# Does it count as multicollinearity if an independent variable is perfectly correlated with the dependent variable?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, multicollinearity

Obviously i want to avoid multicollinarity but the textbook only mentions  relationships between explanatory variables. my dependent variable is TOTALPRICE (price plus postage costs) and i wanted to include POSTAGECOST as an explanatory variable - is this a problem? thank you

Comment: should clarify, i only expect there to be a perfect correlation between postage and totalprice (for example bidders on ebay, my market analysed, may not fully incorporate postage fees into bidding strategies)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is not a case of collinearity.

However, if you already know the price of the postage, I'd rather recommend subtracting it from the total price and trying to regress on the pure letter price. This way you represent the problem better and simplify your model.

Comment: Thanks Kevin!  to press you a little further, i have two (seller representational) explanatory variables: "feedback score" (a measure of lifetime positive reviews - negative reviews) and "12 month positives" (positive reviews placed in the last 12 months only). would these two be perfectly correlated even though one is only for 12 months and hence not a perfect predictor of the other?

Comment: I guess that would depend on the nature of the store. I'd imagine that it would be possible for stores to have different performance over time; it all depends on the domain of the problem.

Comment: I'm analysing how sellers reputations impact action revenue (if at all), just wanted to know if i should include both measures? i think i can not as, by definition, there is an exact relationship between the two

Comment: i have other controls as well, just concerned about multicollinearity between these two independent variables

Comment: I think you're on the right track.